# Python. Проблема с конвертацией в .exe

Tags: python-3.x

Если вкратце, то моя проблема в том, что я не могу совершить конвертацию в exe. Я пробовал установить pythoninstaller через pip, но pip была "неизвестной командой". Я покопался в PATH, указал все пути, которые вели к папке с установленным python и к файлу scripts. В общем,по гайду все делал. Но в итоге, на pip консоль стала отвечать что-то типа этого: fatal error... . Я пытался переустановить python, но теперь при переустановке не появляется папка scripts.К слову, я качал его с офиц. сайта. При переустановке теперь появляется совсем другое окно, не такое, как было в первый раз. Как-будто на компьютере уже скачене питон и предлагается добавить что-то, пофиксить или удалить, но с компьютера я все вроде и удалил, но при нажатии на uninstall появляется ошибка(скрины ниже)
Я очень запутался и не знаю, что делать. Прошу помощи и надеюсь на нее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Repair не помогает?  Попробуйте заново установить и потом удалить инсталлятором.  Не поможет - выложите текст лог файла.